# Unity 3D - Grappling Gun not making Player lift off the ground at all?

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I have the following code (based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xgh4v1w5DxU but tried to convert to work with *world space* points for Third Person Character usage):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrapplingGun : MonoBehaviour
{

    private LineRenderer lr;
    public Vector3 grapplePoint;
    public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
    public Transform gunTip, player;
    private float maxDistance; //how far away we can grapple to
    private SpringJoint joint;
    public GameObject camera3;


    void Awake()
    {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartGrapple();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            StopGrapple();
        }               
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        DrawRope();            
    }

    void StartGrapple()
    {
        Ray ray = camera3.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitResult, 1000))
        {
            print("Grapple connected!");
            grapplePoint = hitResult.point;
            joint = player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;
            float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(player.position, grapplePoint);

            //The distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point.
            joint.maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 1000f;
            joint.minDistance = 0f;

            joint.spring = 4.5f;
            joint.damper = 7f;
            joint.massScale = 4.5f;

            lr.positionCount = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Grapple did not connect!");
        }
    }

    void DrawRope()
    {
        if (!joint) return;

        lr.SetPosition(0, gunTip.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, grapplePoint);
    }

    void StopGrapple()
    {
        lr.positionCount = 0;
        Destroy(joint);
    }
}
```

What is happening is that when I play the project and click on a terrain, the Grapple line gets drawn, but the Player does not move at all; it just stays grounded.

[image]

For testing purposes, I have also created a capsule with a Rigidbody attached and tried setting that as the player to see if it moved then, but it too remained grounded.

What might be going wrong in the code that makes it so that the Player doesn't move towards the GrapplePoint? Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation, the SpringJoint tries to maintain the same distance between the objects that existed when it first spawned. So, if the player is still at the same place they were when you created the SpringJoint, the joint will exert 0 force on them.

Comment: If this doesn't solve the issue, I would also make sure the Character Movement script isn't overriding your grapple code in any way and they both play nicely together.

Comment: @DMGregory What variables do you recommend adjusting to make it so that the player is always pulled towards where they hit? I tried adjusting maxDistance and minDistance a lot but even when they're very small numbers, Player will often stand still if grappling something. I can change `joint.spring` to a large number for momentum but that doesn't feel like it solves the issue; what I am hoping for is something that always pulls Player towards it when they click but at a reasonable speed.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might not want a joint at all, but a script that uses AddForce each FixedUpdate to move your player the way you want it to.